# Closedness of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Please consider my following proof:

Let $A_j=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}[q-\frac{1}{j},q+\frac{1}{j}]$. Then $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$. Since the intersection of countably many closed sets is necessarily closed, we conclude $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed...however, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e\notin\mathbb{Q}$, so $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed??

Clearly I'm missing something: I know $\mathbb{Q}$ is provably not closed but the former method tells otherwise.

The motivation in asking this question is to find an alternative way at proving the Cantor set is a closed set: one method I had been taught is that since the Cantor set is the countable intersection of closed sets, we can say it's closed.

Thank you!

Comment: Every real number is within $\epsilon$ of a rational, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: The intersecton of the $A_j$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$, not just $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Since countable unions of closed subsets are not necessarily closed, what makes you believe that $A_j$ is closed?

Comment: This isn't your issue, but the intersection of *any* number of closed sets is closed; it doesn't matter if there are countably many.

Comment: Closed with respect to what topology?  In what space?  $\mathbb{Q}$ is certainly closed in itself, but is not closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.  You should edit the question to explain which topology is being considered.  You might also wan to think about your assertion that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the intersection of the intervals you have specified.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good point. That's my bad. I literally wrote this question with the understanding that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence the set I introduced would be $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Each set $ A _ j $ is all of $ \mathbb R $, so their intersection is also $ \mathbb R $.

Let $ B _ { q , j } $ be $ [ q - 1 / j , q + 1 / j ] $ (for rational $ q $ and natural $ j $), so that $ A _ j = \bigcup _ q B _ { q , j } $.  I wonder if you're thinking that
$$ \textstyle \bigcap _ j A _ j = \bigcap _ j \bigcup _ q B _ { q , j } \overset ? = \bigcup _ q \bigcap _ j B _ { q , j } = \bigcup _ q \{ q \} = \mathbb Q \text . $$  But the step marked with a question mark is not valid.

For example, $ e = \lim _ n ( 1 + 1 / n ) ^ n $ is in $ \bigcap _ j \bigcup _ q B _ { q , j } $, because for each $ j $, you can approximate $ e $ to within $ 1 / j $ by some rational number $ q $, although which rational number $ q $ is will depend on $ j $.  But $ e \notin \bigcup _ q \bigcap _ j B _ { q , j } $, because there is no single rational number $ q $ such that you can approximate $ e $ to within any tolerance $ 1 / j $ by the same number $ q $ no matter what $ j $ is.

Answer (score 0):

As people are noting in the comments, $$\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_j = \mathbb{R}$$

For instance, pick a real number $r$. Then, there is a sequence $\{q_i\}$ of rational numbers so that $q_i \to r$. In otherwords, for every $j \geq 1$, there is a natural number $N>0$ such that if $i > N$, then $|q_i - r| < \frac{1}{j}$. This means that $r \in [q_i - 1/j, q_i + 1/j] \subset A_j$ for every $i > N$. But as $j$ is arbitrary, we obtain $r \in A_j$ for every $j$.

Answer (score -3):

The interval $[q-1/j,q+1/j]$ is only closed if you view it as a subset of the real numbers, or all real $x$ s.t. $q-(1/j) \leq x \leq q+(1/j)$. The set of all rational's $w$ s.t. $q-(1/j) \leq w \leq q+(1/j)$ is not a closed set in R.

Comment: You are being downvoted (not by me) because your statement about intervals in $\Bbb{Q}$ is incorrect. By the definition of the subspace topology, a subspace of $\Bbb{Q}$ is closed iff it is the intersection $\Bbb{Q} \cap X$, where $X$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb{R}$. The intersection $\Bbb{Q} \cap [q - 1/j, q + 1/j]$ is therefore closed in $\Bbb{Q}$. (it would also be open if you took $j$ to be irrational.)

Comment: Oops. Forgot to specify it was closed in R.